# Drupal - News with accordion / toggle effect and resizing image

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drupal, toggle, accordion

I would like to make a news portal, where next to the post excerpts there will be an image. When you click on the image, the title or the post excerpt , the whole content will be shown (accordion / toggle effect), resizing automatically, in the responsive way, the assigned picture. How to do that on any drupal theme? Example – news.google.com

Graphic explanation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eZkZ.jpg

Maybe there is an extension / module or template that allows for a simple adaptation of such a solution? I know there are accordion plugins, but I do not know how to apply them to the images auto-expand on-click along with content.

Thank you!

Comment: Any oher ideas / suggestions / helpful advices?

Answer (score 0):

This is more front-end than drupal question.
And "how" - you have to make your own theme by inheriting some other (if you don't want to start from scratch).

Then, you have what will that your page be? Node in some new content type or a view or something else.

Then, find some documentation/tutorial how to theme that kind of page.

You must have some deeper understanding how the drupal works before going to real work.

Comment: Thank you Milan. This is excacly what I am looking for - 'some documentaton/tutorial how to theme that kind of page'. Nothing more, nothing less. I'll appreciate if you could point out something, because I basically can't find anything useful.

Comment: First, you didn't say what version of Drupal you are using? Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 theming is pretty different.

Comment: Drupal 8, but can change to 7 if it will be much easier for instance...